# How do I get a reference to the Jackson Object Mapper in a jersey2 / hk2 application

Tags: java, json, dependency-injection, jersey-2.0, hk2

I have a jersey2 application configured for JSON support via Jackson, adding

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
    <version>${jersey.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

in the POM file and

```
public MyApplication() {
    ...
    register(JacksonFeature.class)
    ...
}
```

in my application. Everything works, my resources get deserialized POJOs as arguments

```
@POST @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public void blah(MyPojo p) {
    ...
}
```

Now one of thoese resources needs a reference to Jackson's `ObjectMapper` to do some deserialization on its own. I've tried doing something like

```
@Inject
public MyResource(@Context ObjectMapper mapper) {
    ...
}
```

or

```
@GET
public String foo(@Context ObjectMapper mapper) {
    ...
}
```

but in both cases the reference to `mapper` is null. How can I inject a reference to the `ObjectMapper` in my resources?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First there is no default `ObjectMapper` used by the Jackson provider. It doesn't use an `ObjectMapper` at all actually. It makes use of other Jackson APIs to handle the (de)serialization.

If you want to use/inject a single `ObjectMapper` instance, then you should just create a `Factory` for it

```
public class ObjectMapperFactory implements Factory<ObjectMapper> {

    final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    @Override
    public ObjectMapper provide() {
        return mapper;
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose(ObjectMapper t) {}   
}
```

Then bind it

```
register(new AbstractBinder(){
    @Override
    public void configure() {
        bindFactory(ObjectMapperFactory.class)
            .to(ObjectMapper.class).in(Singleton.class);
    }
});
```

One thing should be noted is that any configuration of the `ObjectMapper` is **not thread safe**. So say you tried to configure it from your resource method, those operations are not thread safe.

Another thing to note with the Jackson provider, is that if we provide a `ContextResolver`, like [mentioned by @Laurentiu L](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30259145/2587435), then the Jackson provider will switch to using our `ObjectMapper`. In which case, if you want to use that same `ObjectMapper`, then you can look it up in the `Factory`. For example

```
public class ObjectMapperFactory implements Factory<ObjectMapper> {

    private final Providers providers;
    final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    public ObjectMapperFactory(@Context Providers providers) {
        this.providers = providers;
    }

    @Override
    public ObjectMapper provide() {
        ContextResolver<ObjectMapper> resolver = providers.getContextResolver(
                ObjectMapper.class, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        if (resolver == null) { return mapper; }

        return resolver.getContext(null);
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose(ObjectMapper t) {}   
}
```

For the above to work (use a single `ObjectMapper`), you need to make sure to implement the `ContextResolver<ObjectMapper>`, and make sure to annotation the `ContextResolver` with the corresponding `@Produces` and `@Consumes` media types.

Comment: according to jackson documentation ObjectMapper intances are thread-safe as long as no reconfiguration takes place.
"Mapper instances are fully thread-safe provided that ALL configuration of the instance occurs before ANY read or write calls."

https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html

Comment: @RicardNàcherRoig Isn't that what I said? _"One thing should be noted is that any configuration of the ObjectMapper is not thread safe"_. If not worded correctly, that's what I meant. You should not try to reconfigure the mapper at runtime; That same mapper may be being used for another request.

Comment: Thank @paul-samsotha for your response. In my opinion, It is not worded correctly or at least I think that the explanation from Jackson API documentation is by far more clear. I wasted some time thinking that ObjectMapper was not ever thread-safe.

Answer (score 4):

Aside from the JacksonFeature you need to register a ContextResolver for ObjectMapper.

Simple example from the [Documentation](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/media.html#d0e8410) at 9.1.4.2. Configure and register

> ```
> @Provider
> public class MyObjectMapperProvider implements ContextResolver<ObjectMapper> {
>
>     final ObjectMapper defaultObjectMapper;
>
>     public MyObjectMapperProvider() {
>         defaultObjectMapper = createDefaultMapper();
>     }
>
>     @Override
>     public ObjectMapper getContext(Class<?> type) {
>         return defaultObjectMapper;
>     }
>
>     private static ObjectMapper createDefaultMapper() {
>         final ObjectMapper result = new ObjectMapper();
>         result.configure(Feature.INDENT_OUTPUT, true);
>
>         return result;
>     }
>
>     // ...
> }
> ```

Complete code example 
[available on Github](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/2.17/examples/json-jackson/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/examples/jackson/MyObjectMapperProvider.java)

You will also need to register it

> ```
>         .register(MyObjectMapperProvider.class)
> ```

Comment: That works, but since I have no need (yet?) of a custom provided `ObjectMapper` I was hoping for a way to use Jersey's created one instead of providing my own.

Comment: If anyone is having "problem: abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types" with Dropwizard even though you registered a module with `addAbstractTypeMapping`, this solution fixed the issue like a charm (just register your module in `createDefaultMapper` and register this `Provider` with `environment.jersey().register()` in the `run()` of your `Application`)!